# Generate words (car brands/models) with mistakes

Tags: php, mysql, fuzzy-search

I am developing a fuzzy search mechanism. I have car brands/models and cities in database (mysql)(english and russian names) - about 1000 items. User can enter this words with mistakes or in translit. Now I am retrieving all these words from db and compare each word in loop with user entered word (using livenstein distance and other functions).
Is there any way to generate many forms of each word (car brands/models) + words with mistakes, because I want to retrieve these words from db (using like sql operator). For example: I have car brand: Toyota and I want to generate - Tokota, Tobota, Toyoba, Tayota, Тойота, Токота, Тобота (russian) - many many forms of each word. And user can enter any of this word and I can find that it is Toyota he means.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a function called `SOUNDEX` in MySQL. I don't know it is what you need.
For example:

```
SELECT SOUNDEX('Toyyota') == SOUNDEX('Toyota')
```

Here is from the MySQL Document

> Returns a soundex string from str. Two strings that sound almost the
>   same should have identical soundex strings. A standard soundex string
>   is four characters long, but the SOUNDEX() function returns an
>   arbitrarily long string. You can use SUBSTRING() on the result to get
>   a standard soundex string. All nonalphabetic characters in str are
>   ignored. All international alphabetic characters outside the A-Z range
>   are treated as vowels.
>
> This function, as currently implemented, is intended to work well with
>   strings that are in the English language only. Strings in other
>   languages may not produce reliable results.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Comment: thank you very much. but i have a lot of words in russian language too.

Comment: i need to search like Тойота, Токота, Тобота, Toyota,Toyyota